# Flutter - Firebase ses a deprecated API

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle

I am getting the below warnings. I sometimes get the warning and sometimes I don't. My question is how can I remove these warnings?

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=24
flutter.targetSdkVersion=32
flutter.compileSdkVersion=33
```

```dart
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_starter_project...             7.5s

 Building with sound null safety 

Note: /home/saurav/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_functions-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/functions/FlutterFirebaseFunctionsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/saurav/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-9.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/analytics/FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/saurav/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_app_installations-0.1.1+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/installations/firebase_app_installations/FirebaseInstallationsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/saurav/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-9.0.20/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/saurav/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_in_app_messaging-0.6.0+20/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/inappmessaging/FirebaseInAppMessagingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/saurav/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_dynamic_links-4.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/dynamiclinks/FlutterFirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/saurav/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-12.0.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/messaging/JobIntentService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/saurav/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_performance-0.8.2+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/performance/FlutterFirebasePerformancePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/saurav/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_remote_config-2.0.13/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firebaseremoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfigPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             43.0s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
```

File: pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: app
description: Write your flutter project description here.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 0.0.1+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # localization
  intl: ^0.17.0

  # firebase
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  firebase_analytics: ^9.2.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.0
  cloud_functions: ^3.3.3
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.3
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.5.3
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.1.1
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.6.0+9
  firebase_app_installations: ^0.1.0+8
  firebase_performance: ^0.8.0+7
  firebase_database: ^9.0.8
  firebase_remote_config: ^2.0.2

  # local notifications
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0

  # annotations
  freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0
  json_annotation: ^4.6.0

  # Equatable
  equatable: ^2.0.3

  # bloc
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  hydrated_bloc: ^8.1.0

  # auto routes
  auto_route: ^4.2.1

  # dio
  dio: ^4.0.4
  dio_cache_interceptor: ^3.2.6
  dio_cache_interceptor_hive_store: ^3.1.1

  # hive
  hive: ^2.1.0
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0

  # functional programming
  dartz: ^0.10.1

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  # responsive ui builder
  flutter_responsive_builder: ^0.0.1

  # widgets
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  shimmer: ^2.0.0

  # native splash screens
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.5

  # url launcher
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5

  # media players
  video_player: ^2.4.5
  audioplayers: ^1.0.1

  # svg support
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.1+1

  # permissions
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0

  # secure local storage
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2

  # dependency_injections
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  injectable: ^1.5.3

  # plus packages
  package_info_plus: ^1.4.2
  device_info_plus: ^4.0.0

  # connectivity test
  internet_connection_checker: ^0.0.1+4

  # location
  geolocator: ^9.0.1

  # device preview
  device_preview: ^1.1.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # test
  test: ^1.20.2

  # bloc test
  bloc_test: ^9.0.3

  # mocktail
  mocktail: ^0.3.0

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

  # freezed
  freezed: ^2.1.0+1

  # json serialization
  json_serializable: ^6.3.1

  # generators
  injectable_generator: ^1.5.4

  # build runner
  build_runner: ^2.1.8



# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  generate: true

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/svgs/

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```